# Kernel Panic: VFS : Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (179,7) after unplugging. Is SD corrupted?

Tags: raspbian, shutdown

I found documentation about 179,2 or 179,6 but never 179,7. This

```
Panic:VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,7)
```

is happening the second time now. I admit I was lazy and just unplugged the microUSB but is it really corrupted? The first time this happened I can just reinstall the whole raspbian, etc. Working fine afterward. If it is truely corrupted, is it possible to fix this 179, 7 error instead of reinstall the whole thing?

Comment: Pretty sure the number is essentially meaningless, it is just a major/minor device id -- it does not indicate a different kind of error from whatever you read about 179,2 or 6.

Comment: 2 and 6 seems to have different solutions. Anyway, I'll try to do fsck to block7. If it works, it works. If not I'll just wipe and reinstall.

Comment: You should start by putting it in another computer and running `e2fsck` on the partition containing the root filesystem.  If that is too awkward and all you are able to do is "wipe and reinstall", then there's not much point in thinking or researching it, you only have one choice available to you.

Comment: I've probably had to pull the plug on a (usually fairly idle) pi more than a hundred times, and never had any fs corruption that I'm aware of (fsck will by default be automatically run at boot when the root fs was not cleanly unmounted, so minor issues issues may go unnoticed).  That is fairly normal; excessive and recurrent corruption is unusual, so you may want to try using a fresh new card.

Answer (score 1):

This `unknown-block (179,7)` problem has happened to me couple of times now after `sudo reboot`.

Both times I could fix it by connecting the SD card to MacBook Pro running Ubuntu and executing `sudo fsck.ext4 -y /dev/sdc7`.